# I cannot parse multi-row json array and put it into the html elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

```html
var dataJSON = '[{"FeeType":"Domestic POS Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"Domestic PIN Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"International POS Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"International PIN Declined Fee ","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"ATM Domestic Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"One (1) no cost ATM withdrawal per deposit1, then $1.75 per transaction thereafter","FeeAmount":"1.75"},{"FeeType":"Domestic ATM Balance Inquiry Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per ATM Balance Inquiry","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"Domestic ATM Declined Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.50"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Withdrawal Fee <sup>1</sup>","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"3.00"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Balance Fee ","FeeDescription":"per ATM Balance Inquiry","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"International ATM Declined Fee","FeeDescription":"per declined transaction","FeeAmount":"0.95"},{"FeeType":"OTC Withdrawal Fee","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"4.00"},{"FeeType":"International OTC Withdrawal Fee","FeeDescription":"per transaction","FeeAmount":"4.00"},{"FeeType":"Currency Conversion Fee","FeeDescription":"3% of transaction amount","FeeAmount":"3.00%"},{"FeeType":"Card Replacement Fee","FeeDescription":"One (1) no cost replacement per calendar year or upon expiration; $5.00 per request thereafter for lost, stolen, and damaged cards.","FeeAmount":"5.00"},{"FeeType":" Expedited Card Replacement Fee ","FeeDescription":"$20.00 (per Card; an additional fee when a Card is reissued or replaced for any reason with requested expedited delivery)","FeeAmount":"20.00"},{"FeeType":"Check Refund Fee","FeeDescription":"$12.50 per refund check (When a refund check is issued for the remaining Card balance.","FeeAmount":"12.5"}]';


var dataObject = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
var listItemString = $('#listItem').html();

dataObject.forEach(buildNewList);

function buildNewList(item, index) {
  var listItem = $('<li class="collection-item">' + listItemString + '</li>');
  var listItemTitle = $('.title', listItem);
  listItemTitle.html(item.FeeType);
  var listItemDesc = $('.description', listItem);
  listItemDesc.html(item.FeeDescription);
  $('#myUL').append(listItem);
}
            
      
            

var myObj2 = {
 "kelimeler": [
 {
   "title": "",
   "description": "T�rkiyenin en b�y�k do_rudan sat�_ _irketi"
 },
 {
   "title": "Aktif Temsilci",
   "description": "Bir kampanyada sipari_ veren ve �d�l sat�_ tutar� s�f�rdan b�y�k olan temsilci"
 },

] }
```

I found some code on the internet. 
var dataObject = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
this works perfectly but it is really hard for me to manage a single line json array. I just want to use myObj2 and access the title and desciption.

How can I access the elements inside myObj2 > 'keliemeler' . I tried item.kelimeler.title something but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

item.kelimeler will never shown since it's only in myObj2, and item is taken from dataJSON that doesn't have kelimeler.